# How to groupby by aggregating different keys in SQL

Tags: sql

I have tables like below.

I would like to `groupby` by generating new keys like `D`,`D`means `A`or`B`

In this case,`count`in `D` is `2` because`A`and`B`has 1 record each.

Are there any way to generate new keys and groupby by using this?

```
product sex  age 
A        M   10
B        M   20
C        F   30
```

My desired result is like below.

```
product    count
C            1
D (A orB)    2
```

If you have same experience please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Use a case expression to put A and B together as D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the column `product` you must group by a derived column that matches your condition:

```
select 
  case when product in ('A', 'B') then 'D' else product end product,
  count(*)
from tablename
group by case when product in ('A', 'B') then 'D' else product end
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v73bKqLcf8mivp83QyVPPp/1).
Results:

```
| newproduct | count(*) |
| ---------- | -------- |
| C          | 1        |
| D          | 2        |
```

Comment: Depending on SQL DB it is possible that you won't be able to use alias in GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL compliant query, use a `case` expression in a *derived table* to put A and B into D. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select product, count(*)
from
(
    select case when product in ('A', 'B') then 'D' else product end product
    from tablename
) dt
group by product
```